# Validate File Type(Audio/Video) Using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 for my project. I need some help to validate the file upload. Functionality is like below,

- fileType - audio/video file
- file.mp3, file.mp4, file.3gb

So while submitting(Rest Client through PostMan) the above fields i need to validate the file for "audio extension(.mp3, etc)" if fileType is"audio".

Same way i need to validate the file for video extension if fileType is "video(.mp4,.3gb)"

I tried to do that but there is an option to validate audio/video extension without checking the value of fileType as below,

```
'file' => 'mimes:mp3,mp4,3gb'
```

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: just wanted to know, are you using form requests for validation?

Comment: Through Post Man (RestFul Client)

Comment: You are checking the api via POSTMAN. what I am asking is are you using a formRequest for validation or your validation logic is inside controller?

Comment: using formRequest

Comment: added an answer, can you please try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using form requests, try with below code

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'some_field' => 'required',
    ];

    //  if fileType is audio
    if ($this->input('fileType') == 'audio') {
        $rules['file'] = 'mimes:mp3,mp4';
    }

    //if fileType is video
    if ($this->input('fileType') == 'video') {
         $rules['file'] = 'mimes:mp4,3gp';

    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Change the field names and validation rules as per your requirement.

Comment: mp3 validation is not working. but text is working if i add text instead of mp3 :(

Comment: can you show on a pastebin your view, formRequest and controller code?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide following validation rule for mp3

```
 $validation_args = [
    'file' => 'required|mimes:mpeg',
 ];
```